# Backup strategy for django

Tags: django, deployment, backup

I recently deployed a couple of web applications built using django (on webfaction). 
These would be some of the first projects of this scale that i am working on, so I wanted to know what an effective backup strategy was for maintaining backups both on webfaction and an alternate location.

EDIT:

What i want to backup?

Database and user uploaded media. (my code is managed via git)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a one size fits all answer especially since you haven't said **what** you intend to backup. My usual MO:

- Source code: use source control such as svn or git. This means that you will usually have: dev, deploy and repository backups for code (specially in a drsc).
- Database: this also depends on usage, but usually:

  - Have a dump_database.py management command that will introspect settings and for each db  will output the correct db dump command (taking into consideration the db type and also the database name).
  - Have a cron job **on another server** that connects through ssh to the application server, executes the dump db management command, tars the sql file with the db name + timestamp as the file name and uploads it to another server (amazon's s3 in my case).
- Media file: e.g. user uploads. Keep a cron job on another server that can ssh into the application server and calls rsync to another server.

The thing to keep in mind though, it what is the intended purpose of the backup.
If it's accidental (be it disk failure, bug or sql injection) data loss or simply restoring, you can keep those cron jobs on the same server.

If you also want to be safe in case the server is compromised, you cannot keep the remote backup credentials (sshkeys, amazon secret etc) on the application server! Or else an attacker will gain access to the backup server.

Comment: Instead of dump_database.py I would recommend using your database's dump tool, e.g. mysqldump. Very simple, works for any set of Django models, lower maintenance cost. I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear, I meant you can write your own dump db that can introspect settings and generate a db agnostic command